# How can I insert the following json into room persistence?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-room, local-database

I find myself in the following situation when using the Room library on Android, I am trying to create a store but I need to insert the amount and the respective item. But I don't know how to save the following json format in room, I would really appreciate your help

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "quantitiy": 3,
    "item": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Huevos Frescampo X30",
        "description": "Huevo Rojo A Insuperable, 30 Unidad(es). 1032680",
        "price": 8950,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-08T20:13:33",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-08T20:13:33"
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "quantitiy": 2,
    "item": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Banano Criollo",
        "description": "Banano Criollo",
        "price": 630,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-08T20:13:33",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-08T20:13:33"
    }
}]
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "cart")
data class Cart (
        @PrimaryKey
        val id: Long,
        val quantitiy: Long,
        val item: ItemC
)

@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class ItemC (
        val id: Long,
        val name: String,
        val description: String,
        val price: Long,
        val createdAt: String,
        val updatedAt: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a json file in assets folder

```
class MockItemFactory constructor(
 
    private val application: Application
) {

companion object {
    const val KEY_FIRST_START = "FIRST_START"
}


    fun generateMockList(): List<Cart> {
        val response = application.assets.readAssetsFile("response.json")
        return GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response, Array<Cart>::class.java).asList()
    }
    
    private fun AssetManager.readAssetsFile(fileName: String): String =
        open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

}
```

and insert these items using you `dao` in your database class when creating it or in Activity using `KEY_FIRST_START` to populate it with your items only once

Comment: I am getting this list, but it does not solve my problem, the idea is to be able to make the same model in room
:(
`[InvoiceItems(quantitiy=3, item=Item(id=1, name=Huevos Frescampo X30, description=Huevo Rojo A Insuperable, 30 Unidad(es). 1032680, price=8950, img_url=null, createdAt=2020-08-08T20:13:33, updatedAt=2020-08-08T20:13:33)), InvoiceItems(quantitiy=2, item=Item(id=2, name=Banano Criollo, description=Banano Criollo, price=630, img_url=null, createdAt=2020-08-08T20:13:33, updatedAt=2020-08-08T20:13:33))]
2020-08-09`

Comment: Since I must insert, get, following the same model of the json object, The problem is exactly in relating the entities in room